# Как распарсить XML в многомерный словарь?

Tags: python, словари

сломал голову, прошу помочь. Есть некий XML

```
<svc>
 <id_ip v="010.010.010.171" d="c" id="0" />
 <id_port v="600" d="c" id="1" />
 <id_ip v="031.031.031.112" d="a" id="2" />
 <id_port v="080" d="a" id="3" />
</svc>
```

Для дальнейшей обработки хочу привести к подобному виду : (может что со скобками напутал, но идея наверное понятна)

```
{svc:
    ['id_ip'][0]{{"v":"010.010.010.171"},{"d":"c"}},
             [1]{{"v":"031.031.031.112"},{"d":"a"}},
    ['id_port'][0]{{"v":"600"},{"d":"c"}},
               [1]{{"v":"080"},{"d":"a"}}
}
```

Файл распарсиваю с помощью ElementTree, сканирую пока не найду блок SVC. Для примера сразу привел его. В дальнейшем те же действия делаю с другим файлом (эталоном) и сравниваю словари построчно, удаляя совпадения. Мне нужна информация для лога, поэтому хотел бы получить подобную структуру. В случае расхождения (наличия не удаленных записей в словаре) в лог напишу что в "блоке SVC Первый/второй параметр ID_IP не совпадает атрибут V". При этом укажу и эталонное значение и проверяемое. На РНР бы сделал многомерный массив и заполнял его, а с Питоном недавно занимаюсь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я вас правильно понял, вам нужно словарь поправить?

```
data = {
    'svc': [
        {'id_ip': [
            {'v': '010.010.010.171', 'd': 'c'},
            {'v': '031.031.031.112', 'd': 'a'}
        ]},
        {'id_port': [
            {'v': '600', 'd': 'c'},
            {'v': '080', 'd': 'a'}
        ]}
    ]
}

# Обращение к первому элементу в списке 'svc'
first_svc = data['svc'][0]

# Обращение к параметру 'id_ip' внутри первого элемента 'svc'
id_ip = first_svc['id_ip']

# Обращение к параметру 'v' внутри первого элемента 'id_ip'
v_value = id_ip[0]['v']

# Обращение к параметру 'd' внутри первого элемента 'id_ip'
d_value = id_ip[0]['d']

# Обращение к параметру 'v' второго элемента 'id_ip'
v_value2 = id_ip[1]['v']

# Обращение к параметру 'd' второго элемента 'id_ip'
d_value2 = id_ip[1]['d']

# Обращение к первому элементу в списке 'id_port'
id_port = data['svc'][1]['id_port']

# Обращение к параметру 'v' внутри первого элемента 'id_port'
v_value_port = id_port[0]['v']

# Обращение к параметру 'd' внутри первого элемента 'id_port'
d_value_port = id_port[0]['d']

# Обращение к параметру 'v' второго элемента 'id_port'
v_value2_port = id_port[1]['v']

# Обращение к параметру 'd' второго элемента 'id_port'
d_value2_port = id_port[1]['d']

# Вывод результатов
print(f'v_value: {v_value}, d_value: {d_value}')
print(f'v_value2: {v_value2}, d_value2: {d_value2}')
print(f'v_value_port: {v_value_port}, d_value_port: {d_value_port}')
print(f'v_value2_port: {v_value2_port}, d_value2_port: {d_value2_port}')

# Консоль:
v_value: 010.010.010.171, d_value: c
v_value2: 031.031.031.112, d_value2: a
v_value_port: 600, d_value_port: c
v_value2_port: 080, d_value2_port: a
```

Вот расписал как его можно собрать:

```
# Создаем пустые списки
id_ip_list = []
id_port_list = []

# Добавляем словари в список 'id_ip'
id_ip_list.append({'v': '010.010.010.171', 'd': 'c'})
id_ip_list.append({'v': '031.031.031.112', 'd': 'a'})

# Добавляем словари в список 'id_port'
id_port_list.append({'v': '600', 'd': 'c'})
id_port_list.append({'v': '080', 'd': 'a'})

# Создаем словарь 'svc' с элементами 'id_ip' и 'id_port'
data = {
    'svc': [
        {'id_ip': id_ip_list},
        {'id_port': id_port_list}
    ]
}

# Выводим результат
print(data)

# Консоль:
{'svc': [{'id_ip': [{'v': '010.010.010.171', 'd': 'c'}, {'v': '031.031.031.112', 'd': 'a'}]}, {'id_port': [{'v': '600', 'd': 'c'}, {'v': '080', 'd': 'a'}]}]}
```

И последний пример:

```
# Создаем пустой список id_ip_list
id_ip_list = []

# Добавляем элементы в список по одному ключу за раз
element_1 = {'v': '010.010.010.171'}
element_1['d'] = 'c'
id_ip_list.append(element_1)

element_2 = {'v': '031.031.031.112'}
element_2['d'] = 'a'
id_ip_list.append(element_2)

# Печать списка
print(f'id_ip_list: {id_ip_list}')

# Консоль:
id_ip_list: [{'v': '010.010.010.171', 'd': 'c'}, {'v': '031.031.031.112', 'd': 'a'}]
```

Comment: Мне бы подсказать как можно формировать. Вариант - либо построчно, но как для второго параметра записать добавление {"d":"c"}. Либо из xml строки сформировать словарь для 2 параметров {"v":"010.010.010.171"},{"d":"c"} и потом добавить сразу... К концу дня уже не могу сообразить.

Comment: Обновил для вас ответ.

Comment: Спасибо, почти что оно. Но мне нужно указать где IP_1 а где IP_2. Пока получается что нужно самому контролировать и указывать нумерацию для повторяющихся параметров. Рассматриваю вариант {'id_ip':[[0:{'v':'1**'},{'d':'1**'}],[1:{'v':'2**'},{'d':'2**'}]]},{'id_port....'}. Хочу индекс списка определять через длину списка. Так как в файлах есть до 10 повторяющихся имен (но не значений) параметров. Буду думать над вашими подсказками.